# Shopify - How to avoid showing free product variants

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

In Shopify we do have the price in the Variants when the product does have variants, but when one of them is without price, the product is shown as "From 0.00" in PLP. Is there a way to remove (or hide) the variants without price in PLP/PDP? Or disallowing publishing products that at least one of its variants is without price?